# Websphere MQ: Proper usage of method createQueue(java.lang.String queueName) in com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I need to clarify the behavior of the method `createQueue(java.lang.String queueName)` from the class `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession`.
If I pass an arbitrary queue name, will it create a temporary queue? In the other hand, what `String` value needs to be passed to get a `Queue` object that represents a static queue configured in the queue manager?
For instance, if I have an object `dest` of type `MQDestination`, I could call `dest.toString()` or according to javadocs or `dest.getStringFromDestination()` (which returns a URI String). Will any of these two results work if passed to the createQueue method mentioned.

The intent of my question is to properly use a Spring's `DynamicDestinationResolver` (takes String and returns Destination) which behind the scenes uses this MQ specific method.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the description of the JMS Session object here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Session.html

In JMS Session.createQueue() does not create a physical queue on the MQ queue manager, rather it's used to connect to one which has already been defined. MQSession.createQueue("Q1"); would result in a Destination object which can be used to refer to the queue 'Q1' which already exists on the queue manager.

For creating a temporary queue you need to use the createTemporaryQueue() method of the MQSession object. Though you have no control over the name of said temporary queue.

Comment: The prefix of the temporary queue can be controlled; there's a property on the Connection Factory that can be used to add a prefix; but the main body of the name is not within the applications control.

Comment: thanks, do you know if the queue name passed to the session, in your example Q1, has to meet certain criteria? For instance, does it need to be a URI? The physical queue name? This seems to be a provider specific consideration, I would like to know how it is for Websphere MQ specifically

Comment: You have the option of specifying either the queue name on the local queue manager (the one you connected to), or specifying a full URI. In my example 'Q1' would be the name of a local queue on the queue manager. IBM have a good page on the various ways of specifying the queue name to createQueue() here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032240_.htm?lang=en